# Law of Cosines Geometry

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Included below is a picture of a geometry question I’ve been tinkering with. I feel like this should involve law of cosines to begin placing the angles, but I’m not sure how to proceed. [image]

Comment: Is angle $ABC$ a right angle? And likewise $CDE$? If so, then $AC$ = 17, and $CE$ = 10. Finally, is $CF$ parallel to $AB$ and $DE$?.

Comment: This is the only given information. If I had that those angles were right, or the parallel piece then I'd have blitzed the problem, but I've been trained to never assume a right angle or parallel lines.

Comment: Yeah, I agree, I wouldn't assume any right angles or parallel lines

Comment: Since $AC,$ $CE,$ and $FE,$ are not given, first redraw the picture without those, and put hinges at the four corners of the quadrilateral $ABCF$ and at $D.$ Then ask if you can bend the whole thing while keeping the stated distances the same but altering the distance $FE.$ It appears to me that you can, and that says you can't tell what the distance $FE$ is with the given information.

Comment: @JosephDeGaetani, Like Michael Hardy said: There are infinite answers, there's no one set length unless we are missing a piece of information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No information about the location of $E$ is given except that its distance from $D$ is $6.$ So let $E$ move all the way around the circle of radius $6$ centered at $D.$ Ask whether the distance $EF$ varies as $E$ moves along that circle. Clearly it does, but all of the specified information about the figure remains as it was; it doesn't change. Therefore the given information is not enough to say what the distance $FE$ is. But it cannot be more than $12+8+6.$

Comment: There is enough info, assuming that the angles are right.. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can get all
the needed info like this,
if angles ABC and CDE are right:

$\tan(ABC) = AB/BC\\
AC = \sqrt{AB^2+BC^2}$

Since you now know
AC, CF, and FA,
you can get
$\cos(ACF)$
from the law of cosines.

$\tan(ECD) = ED/DC\\
CE = \sqrt{CD^2+DE^2}$

Since
$ACB+ACF+FCE+ECD = \pi$,
you can now get
$FCE$.

Since you now know
$FCE, FC, CE$,
you can get
$EF$
from the law of cosines.

Note that
$\tan(x)
=\dfrac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}
=\dfrac{\sqrt{1-\cos^2(x)}}{\cos(x)}
$
so
$\cos^2(x)\tan^2(x)
=1-\cos^2(x)
$
so
$\cos^2(x)(\tan^2(x)+1)
=1
$
or
$\cos(x)
=\dfrac1{\sqrt{\tan^2(x)+1}}
$.

Also note that
$\arctan(x)+\arctan(y)
=\arctan\left(\dfrac{x+y}{1-xy}\right)
$.

Answer (score 0):

[See Figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kG5hY.jpg)

Since angle ABC and CDE are not given therefore there are infinite no. of solutions for this problem. Minute change in angle will cause change in length of FE itself.